# NotImplementedError in publickey.PublicKey().find_program_address() solana-py

Tags: solana, solana-web3js, solana-program-library

I am trying to get the PDA for a mint account in order to get NFT metadata. I am using solana-py library.

```
from solana import publickey

pda = publickey.PublicKey("AHZdk7qrX16vpw4oQgDcyhAR3SJtNS28epaznGrAvFxs").find_program_address(
seeds=[b"metadata"], program_id=publickey.PublicKey("metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s"))
```

But I am getting the following error:

> ...site-packages\solana\publickey.py", line 87, in
> find_program_address
> raise NotImplementedError("find_program_address not implemented")
> NotImplementedError: find_program_address not implemented

What is it wrong?

EDIT 1:

Watched some code and try this but still not working

```
from solana.publickey import PublicKey

METADATA_PROGRAM_ID = PublicKey('metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s')
mint_key = "8Rjxaxy8ZNAGTojzQSAMSPatNiop9C9PRPY5A29qhrCT"

PDA = PublicKey.find_program_address(
        [b'metadata', bytes(METADATA_PROGRAM_ID), bytes(PublicKey(mint_key))],
        METADATA_PROGRAM_ID
    )[0]

print(PDA)
```

EDIT 2:

It was the version of solana-py It was using!
Is working now

Answer (score 1):

`find_program_address` is only defined on the class not on instances of it. try calling `PublicKey.find_program_address`

Comment: Hey thanks for answering. I try it but still getting same error!

`from solana.publickey import PublicKey

METADATA_PROGRAM_ID = PublicKey('metaqbxxUerdq28cj1RbAWkYQm3ybzjb6a8bt518x1s')
mint_key = "8Rjxaxy8ZNAGTojzQSAMSPatNiop9C9PRPY5A29qhrCT"

PDA = PublicKey.find_program_address(
        [b'metadata', bytes(METADATA_PROGRAM_ID), bytes(PublicKey(mint_key))],
        METADATA_PROGRAM_ID
    )[0]

print(PDA)`

Answer (score 1):

```
METADATA_PROGRAM_ID = PublicKey('cndy3Z4yapfJBmL3ShUp5exZKqR3z33thTzeNMm2gRZ')    
PDA = PublicKey.find_program_address(
  [b'candy_machine',  bytes(PublicKey(mint_key))],
  METADATA_PROGRAM_ID
)[0]
```